# How to convert Hex to Ascii in C with and without using sprintf?

Tags: c

I used `strtol` to convert a string to hex, now I need to print it to the screen. I'm not sure if I can use `sprintf` since I only have 20k of memory to use on this board. Alternatives welcome.

Answer (score 10):

To do this manually, the easiest way is to have a table mapping nybbles to ASCII:

```
static const char nybble_chars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Then to convert a byte into 2 hex chars -- assuming `unsigned char` is the best representation for a byte, but making no assumptions about its size -- extract each nybble and get the char for it:

```
void get_byte_hex( unsigned char b, char *ch1, char *ch2 ) {
    *ch1 = nybble_chars[ ( b >> 4 ) & 0x0F ];
    *ch2 = nybble_chars[ b & 0x0F ];
}
```

This extends straightforwardly to wider data types, and should generate reasonably concise code across a wide range of architectures.

Comment: +1 if you add `chars[2] = '\0'` (and some spaces couldn't hurt your code either.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Formatting Codes](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/printf), if your C implementation supports it, it should be easy to print values in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Check your C library for `ltoa` -- the inverse of `strtol`.  Or, write it from scratch (see brone's answer).