# conversion of a uint32_t hex value to an ascii decimal LCD using C

Tags: c, microcontroller, cortex-m

I was just wondering if anyone had any insight on how to convert a uint32_t hex value to a ascii decimal and display it to an LCD. An algorithm would help so I can program it using C code. The hex value i'm getting comes from an ADC that I take and convert to to LCD. The ADC data gives a 16 bit value and the lcd is 16x2

```
void Hex2DecToLCD(){

// Algorithm goes here

}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Hex to Ascii in C with and without using sprintf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710016/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-c-with-and-without-using-sprintf)

Comment: Im going to scale my voltage coming from the ADC with 0x8 then I take that value and make a function to convert the hex to a BCD code

Right now figuring out how to implement a Hex to BCD function in C

Answer (score 0):

```
void Hex_To_BCD_To_LCD(uint32_t ADCData)

 {

   char BCD[5];

   uint32_t Dig_0, Dig_1, Dig_2, Dig_3, Dig_4;

   int i = 0;

   uint32_t temp = 0x0;

   uint32_t bin_inp = ADCData;

   bin_inp *= 0x8; // scale up the ADC value

   temp  = bin_inp;

   Dig_4 = temp/10000;

   BCD[4] = Dig_4 + 0x30;

   temp  = temp - (Dig_4 * 10000);
   Dig_3 = temp/1000;
   BCD[3] = Dig_3 + 0x30;
   temp  = temp - (Dig_3 * 1000);

   Dig_2 = temp/100;
   BCD[2] = Dig_2 + 0x30;
   temp  = temp - (Dig_2 * 100);

   Dig_1 = temp/10;
   BCD[1] = Dig_1 + 0x30;
   temp  = temp - (Dig_1 * 10);

   Dig_0 = temp;
   BCD[0] = Dig_0 + 0x30;

 //Data to LCD
for (i =0; i < 5; i++){

     Data_To_LCD(BCD[i++]);

   }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Julien in 2015 probably works, but I think it's formatting and methodology could be improved a little bit.

My microcontroller relies on `uint8_t` for most integer values, including the transmission of ASCII bytes over UART.

I hope this answer helps whoever is looking for an easy drop-in `uint32_t` replacement for `%lu` in `printf`.

```c
#include <stdint.h>

void putDwordDecimalValue(uint32_t value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        putChar('0');
        return;
    }

    uint32_t valueCopy;
    valueCopy = value;

    int length = 0;
    while (valueCopy != 0) {
        length++;
        valueCopy /= 10;
    }

    int i;
    uint8_t asciiDigits[10];  // Max size of 4294967295 => 10 digits
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        uint8_t lastDigit = value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        asciiDigits[length - (i + 1)] = 0x30 + lastDigit; // 0x30 = 0 in ASCII
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        putChar(asciiDigits[i]);
}
```